# How to export or use component state as hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to use hook to get and set the value of my component WITHOUT PROPS. I import the component and it lists the data returned from the request, ok, but when I use the hook to see the data it returns empty, as if it were another instance.

Initially I used the state of the parent component, but when I needed to change some value of my component, everything would re-render as it affected the state of the parent component, so I want to isolate the state in the child component and use it freely as a hook elsewhere .

How I would like to use:

```js
import MyComp, { useMyHook } from '../../../components/MyComp';

const OtherComp = () => {

    const { data } = useMyHook();

    return(
        <div>
            <button type="button" onClick={() => console.log(data)}>
                click test
            </button>
            <MyComp />
        </div>
    );
};

export default OtherComp;
```

Component render

```
Example1
Example2
```

But the click button log: `[ ]`

Without using external components/libs like redux and etc.

My custom hook:
src/useMyHook.ts

```js
import { useState } from 'react';

export const useMyHook = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState<any[]>([]);

    const addItem = (item: unknown) => {
        setData([...date, item]);
    };

    return { data, setData, addItem};
};

export default useMyHook;
```

My main component:
src/MyComp.tsx

```js
import {useEffect} from 'react';
import useMyHook from './useMyHook';

const MyComp = () => {
    const { data, setData } = useMyHook();

    const req = async() => {
        const {values} = await anyRequest(); // to do any request

        setData(values);
    };

    useEffect(() => { req() },[]);

    return(
        <div>
            {data.map((item) => <p>{item.name}</p>)}
        </div>
    );
};

export { useMyHook };

export default MyComp;
```

src/index.tsx

```js
import MyComp, { useMyHook } from './MyComp';

export default MyComp;

export { useMyHook };
```

Comment: Unless I misunderstood the question, this is situation is identical to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74338945/ui-not-re-rendering-on-state-update-using-custom-hook/74339169

Comment: Every time `useMyHook` is called it creates its own state. It looks like you want to use `React.createContext` and `React.useContext` to store the data globally, and then you can create a hook that calls `useContext` to get the data, and then return your helper functions like `addItem`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To demonstrate my comment:

```js
import React,{useState, createContext} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import useMyHook from './useMyHook'
import Example1 from './Example1'
import Example2 from './Example2'
import OtherComp from './OtherComp'
import {Data, DataSetter} from './types'


type DContext = {
  data:Data,
  setData:DataSetter
}
export const DataContext = createContext({
  data:[],
  setData:()=>{}
} as DContext)

export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState<Data>([])
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <DataContext.Provider value={{data,setData}}>
        <Example1/>
        <Example2/>
        <OtherComp/>
      </DataContext.Provider>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

```js
import { useContext, useCallback } from 'react';
import { DataContext } from './App';

export const useMyHook = () => {
  const { data, setData } = useContext(DataContext);
  // wrapped in useCallback to prevent function from
  // being recreated
  const addItem = useCallback((item: unknown) => {
    setData(prev=>[...prev, item]);
  },[]);

  return { data, setData, addItem };
};

export default useMyHook;
```

`useMyHook` usage:

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Button } from 'react-native';
import useMyHook from './useMyHook';
export default function Example1() {
  const { data, addItem } = useMyHook();

  return (
    <View style={{ width: '100%' }}>
      <Button
        title="Add Item From Example 1"
        onPress={() => {
          addItem(Math.floor(Math.random() * 25) + ' From Example1');
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

A [demo](https://snack.expo.dev/CKWb_pZj7)

Comment: I had already seen that link, I tried to put as much information as possible but forgot about it, another detail is that I shouldn't use something that encompasses the entire application, so I said not to use redux. The reason is that this component will be used by other company applications (the company is creating some components of its own). That is, it has to be a component that another application installs and uses, without needing global state. But I'm already thinking it's impossible :(

Comment: It’s not using redux it’s using the default react context provider. You could make it possible to use externally by exporting DataContext.Provider as a some container

Comment: For an example, react-native-paper have a useTheme hook that allows you to get the current theme, but to use it you need to have your component wrapped in a  ThemeContainer. react-navigation & react-native-gesture-handler does similar things

Comment: Here's an example following that approach https://snack.expo.dev/JgtgOUdAM

Comment: True, even famous components use a global scope around the application. I think I'll try another way, but in fact your answer solves this problem!