# UI not re-rendering on state update using custom hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use `useState` in my custom React hook `useGame` and I was pretty sure that updating state in the custom hook would trigger re-rendering of every component using the hook but it turned out it doesn't work this way

**useGame hook**

```
export const useGame = () => {
    const [stage, setStage] = useState(STAGE.START);
    const [minValue, setMinValue] = useState(DEFAULT_MIN);
    const [maxValue, setMaxValue] = useState(DEFAULT_MAX);
    const [number, setNumber] = useState(generateRandomNumberInRange(minValue, maxValue));

    const generateNumber = () => {
        const newNumber = generateRandomNumberInRange(minValue, maxValue);
        setNumber(newNumber);
    };

    return { stage, setStage, number, generateNumber };
};
```

**Game component**

```
export const Game = () => {
    const { stage } = useGame();

    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column", justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
            {(() => {
                switch (stage) {
                    case STAGE.START:
                        return <Start />;

                    case STAGE.PLAYING:
                        return <Playing />;

                    case STAGE.FINISH:
                        return <Finish />;

                    default:
                        return null;
                }
            })()}
        </div>
    );
};
```

**Start component**

```
export const Start = () => {
    const { setStage } = useGame();

    const handleClick = () => {
        setStage(STAGE.PLAYING);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <button onClick={handleClick}>Start game</button>
        </>
    );
};
```

I was sure that on `handleClick` it would update state `stage` in `useGame` hook, `Game` component would re-render and since the `stage` had changed it would render `Playing` component this time. But it doesn't work this way. Could you please explain me what I am doing wrong and how to fix my code and make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useGame()` calls in `<Game />` and `<Start />` aren't related — they will both have their own states. React doesn't exactly know that your `useGame` hook exists; it only sees that while rendering the `<Game />` component (i.e. calling the `Game` function), `useState` gets called four times, and while rendering the `<Start />` component (again, that is calling the `Start` function), `useState` gets called four times too. React can keep track of the **eight** state values by knowing where the `<Game />` and `<Start />` components exist in its tree model and combining that information with the order of the `useState` calls.

- `Game()`

  - `useGame()` (React **doesn't** see this call)

    - `useState(STAGE.START)` (React sees this) — State #0
    - `useState(DEFAULT_MIN)` (React sees this) — State #1
    - `useState(DEFAULT_MAX)` (React sees this) — State #2
    - `useState(generate…)` (React sees this) — State #3
- `<Start />`

  - `useGame()` (React **doesn't** see this call)

    - `useState(STAGE.START)` (React sees this) — State #4
    - `useState(DEFAULT_MIN)` (React sees this) — State #5
    - `useState(DEFAULT_MAX)` (React sees this) — State #6
    - `useState(generate…)` (React sees this) — State #7

To solve this, you'll either need to move the state up (to a common ancestor component for `<Game />` and `<Start />` which will then pass the states and setters down as props or as a context value) or use an external state manager like Zustand, Redux, MobX etc.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying, Emma, I wasn't aware that state in React custom hooks works this way, I was pretty sure that it made possible to share state between diferent components.